# Getting current domain + directory in php

Tags: php, html

So, I've found a way to get the current directory using `dirname(__FILE__)` and getting the domain with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. While both of these are well and good, they aren't quite what I need them to be.

For instance, if I have a script on `http://mydomain.com/scripts/myscript.php`, I'd like to get `http://mydomain.com/scripts/`. I feel like there should be an easy way to do this and that I've somehow overlooked something.

As an aside, I am currently using the script in a cloud shared hosting environment, so the directory structure is somewhat odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

Comment: That's really weird that that works on my current web server. When I just do `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, it basically gives me the same thing as dirname(__FILE__)

Comment: Doesn't REQUEST_URI also contain the filename?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<?php
     echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

The only problem with that is that dirname returns the parent directory, so if you access http://domain.com/scripts/ directly you'll just get http://domain.com/ withouth the scripts. http://domain.com/scripts/script.php resolves correctly to http://domain.com/scripts/ though.

Answer (score 1):

```
function url_part(){
   $http=isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';

   $part=rtrim($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));

   $domain=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    return "$http"."$domain"."$part";

}

echo url_part;//htts://www.example.net/test
```

Comment: Please explain (in your answer) with text what your code does best. And all other answers fail to do instead of bluntly posting code solely. Downvoted due to missing context. Update and downvote can be unlocked and removed if the edit satisfies.